# How to make a code fragment in ieeetran class

Tags: formatting, ieeetran

What I wish to achieve is rectangle around code, with code in the font format as shown. How should I achieve this format?

[image: Code Fragment example code]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some methods (including the `listing` package already shown by percusse):

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[skipbelow=\topskip,skipabove=\topskip]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{roundcorner=0}

\begin{document}
\title{How to insert framed code}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
% The Abstract
\begin{abstract}
The article shows some methods to framed code.
\end{abstract}

% The Keywords 
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Code, framed, boxes.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Framed code}

\subsection{Using listings}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection{Using fancyvrb}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{Verbatim}

\subsection{Using framed+verbatim}

\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{verbatim}
\end{framed}

\subsection{Using tcolorbox}
% setting for a simple frame
\tcbset{lowerbox=ignored,skin=freelance,frame code={
    \draw (frame.south west)rectangle(frame.north east);

  }
}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{tcblisting}

\subsection{Using mdframed+listings}

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) package and adjust it according to your needs.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<- For dummy text

\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]