# C style structure declarations for IEEETran

Tags: algorithmic

I am writing a document in IEEETran class and I have to include my algorithm in pseudo code. IEEETran class suggests using "algorithmic" package. Can you please suggest me in writing the below structure definition using algorithmic package:

```
struct Node {
    NodePtr left, right;
};
```

struct in the algorithm should be bold.

Comment: The following post may be helpful. Kindly check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books

Comment: I am not looking for a listing package. I want to use algorithmic package

Comment: Okay Let me try!

Comment: Do you mean the `algorithms` package with the `algorithmic` environment or the `algorithmicx` package?

Comment: I am not sure of what `algorithms` package with the `algorithmic` environment is. IEEETran class says the following: `algorithmic.sty was written by Peter Williams and Rogerio Brito.
This package provides an algorithmic environment fo describing algorithms.'

Comment: Can I not directly use the `algorithmic` package?

Comment: `algorithmic` is no distinct package (in [CTAN](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) structure). There it is bundled into the `algorithms` package. AFAIK this package is not intended to serve for C code.

Comment: [The documentation of this package is on CTAN](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf), as it is written in the IEEETran template. This package is for typesetting _algorithms_ in pseudocode though. You should look for a package to typeset C listings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest any package for write algorithms in C style code? Previously I used algorithm2e but IEEETran does not encourage the use of algorithm2e

Comment: You can have a look at the `listings` package. Your question now looks like a duplicate of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65219/how-to-make-a-code-fragment-in-ieeetran-class), I suggest you have a look at its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code. You can remove the numbering afterwards. The same code is also working for the document class `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}
\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Struct Node $\{$
\State Nodeptr left, right;
\State  $\};$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```